# How to copy values from textbox into array of labels?

Tags: c#, arrays, textbox, label

OK Here's what I did and the values which were set vertical are copied in the labels but horizontal. And only one column/row.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Label l;
    private Button bStart;
    private TextBox txtVnes;
    private Label[] pole;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        bStart = new Button();
        bStart.Location = new Point(240, 165);
        bStart.Width = 75;
        bStart.Height = 25;
        bStart.Text = "START";

        txtVnes = new TextBox();
        txtVnes.Location = new Point(240, 10);
        txtVnes.Width = 160;
        txtVnes.Height = 130;
        txtVnes.Multiline = true;

        int a = 0;
        pole = new Label[42];
        for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= 7; j++)
            {
                l = new Label();
                l.Name = "label" + i.ToString() + j.ToString();
                l.Text = "Z";
                l.Width = 20;
                l.Height = 20;
                l.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
                l.Parent = this;
                l.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(100, 149, 237);
                l.Location = new Point(10 + (j - 1) * 25, 15 + (i - 1) * 25);
                pole[a] = l;
                this.Controls.Add(l);
                a++;

            }
        }

        this.Controls.Add(bStart);
        this.Controls.Add(txtVnes);

        bStart.Click += new EventHandler(bStart_Click);

    }


    private void bStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Regex regex = new Regex(@"^(\s)*(\d ){6}\d(\s)*$");
        bool isValid = true;
        string[] ts = txtVnes.Text.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" },
        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);


        if (ts == null || ts.Length < 1 || ts.Length > 6)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Not valid");
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (string t in ts)
            {
                if (regex.IsMatch(t) == false)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Not valid");
                    break;
                }
            }

        }

        if (isValid)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                if (i < ts.Length && regex.IsMatch(ts[i]))
                { 

                    pole[i].Text = ts[i];
                }
                else
                {
                    pole[i].Text = "not valid";
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

[Here's a photo](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/707/formevm.jpg/)

So here is the problem: When I click on the button bStart only one value is copied and replaced in one labe from the array of labels. 
This should work like this: After the user clicks on the button bStart, all values from the textbox txtVnes should be copied in each label in the array of labels. All the labels have text "Z", and after click on the button they should be changed with the values in the textbox txtVnes. As you can see i used `l.Text = txtVnes.Text;` to copy the values, but it doesn't work. I appreciate if you can help me, thank you!

Comment: Please show all pertinent code, but only pertinent code. There are parts we need to see but you are not showing them to us, and you are showing us parts that we really do not care to see.

Comment: I do not see the relation between the two code parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are always setting the text of the same label `l`. Since your labels are in the array `pole`, you should set the text to consecutive `pole` indices.

I you want all the valid texts at the beginning:

```
string[] ts = txtVnes.Text.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
int k = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < ts.Length && k < 6; i++) {
    if (IsValid(ts[i])) { // Where IsValid is a method containing your validation logic.
        pole[k++].Text = ts[i];
    }
}

// Fill remaining labels
for (int i = k; i < 6; i++) {
    pole[i].Text = "not valid";
}
```

Or, if you want vaild and invalid texts mixed:

```
string[] ts = txtVnes.Text.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    if (i < ts.Length && IsValid(ts[i])) { // Where IsValid is a method containing your validation logic.
        pole[i].Text = ts[i];
    } else {
        pole[i].Text = "not valid";
    }
}
```

Note that array indices begin at 0, not at 1.

---

EDIT #2:

The `IsValid` method would look like this:

```
private static Regex regex = new Regex(@"^(\s)*(\d ){6}\d(\s)*$"); 

private static bool IsValid(string s)
{
    return regex.IsMatch(s);
}
```

---

To answer your question in the comment: Yes, my examples above have to be placed in  `bStart_Click`.

And there  is also another error in your form constructor. `this.Controls.Add(l);` should be placed inside the inner for-loop, just after `pole[a] = l;`, otherwise only one label will be visible on your form.

Finally after having implemented and anlyzed your code, I came to the conclusion that you want to be able to enter text in the following format into the textbox and then place the digits into corresponding labels:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
2 3 4 6 7 8 0
0 1 2 6 6 6 7
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
2 3 4 6 7 8 0
0 1 2 6 6 6 7
```

The complete code should look like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Button bStart;
    private TextBox txtVnes;
    private Label[] pole;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        bStart = new Button();
        bStart.Location = new Point(240, 165);
        bStart.Width = 75;
        bStart.Height = 25;
        bStart.Text = "START";
        bStart.Click += new EventHandler(bStart_Click);
        this.Controls.Add(bStart);

        txtVnes = new TextBox();
        txtVnes.Location = new Point(240, 10);
        txtVnes.Width = 160;
        txtVnes.Height = 130;
        txtVnes.Multiline = true;
        this.Controls.Add(txtVnes);

        int a = 0;
        pole = new Label[42];
        for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= 7; j++) {
                var l = new Label();
                l.Name = "label" + i.ToString() + j.ToString();
                l.Text = "Z";
                l.Width = 20;
                l.Height = 20;
                l.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
                l.Parent = this;
                l.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(100, 149, 237);
                l.Location = new Point(10 + (j - 1) * 25, 15 + (i - 1) * 25);
                pole[a] = l;
                this.Controls.Add(l);
                a++;
            }
        }
    }

    private void bStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] ts = txtVnes.Text.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        int row = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < ts.Length && row < 6; i++) {
            if (LineIsValid(ts[i])) {
                for (int col = 0; col < 7; col++) {
                    pole[row * 7 + col].Text = ts[i][2 * col].ToString();
                }
                row++;
            }
        }

        // Fill remaining labels
        for (; row < 6; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < 7; col++) {
                pole[row * 7 + col].Text = "Z";
            }
        }
    }

    private static Regex regex = new Regex(@"^(\s)*(\d ){6}\d(\s)*$");

    private static bool LineIsValid(string line)
    {
        return regex.IsMatch(line);
    }
}
```

Two nested loops are required in bStart_Click as well. One for the rows and one for the columns.

Comment: I'm sorry but I did not understand what should I put in the IsValid method? And the code above it should be in the event bStart_Click, right?

Comment: Well, your Regex validation or what ever you do in order to see if your string is valid. (I did not want to clutter my example with these details.)

Comment: Yes that was my point :) I try it and it works. Thank you very much! This is only a start to my project that I'm doing for school, and I'm new in programming, but thanks to you i started to understand more :) If i get stuck somewhere in the code can i ask for help again? Thank you once again.

Comment: If you are not sure what the code does, use the debugger. This is really a great tool and is very easy to use. Click on the grey border to the left of a line of code in the editor. A brown circle appears. When you run the programm, it will stop at this place. Then you can hover over variables with your mouse and will see their values. You can go step by step through your code with F11.